# Mac Mail application removes attachment when forwarding mails

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, attachments

When I forward email having attachment the recipient is not getting the attachment file. Mail application removes it automatically before forwarding. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Attachments will be part of the email per default **iff** it has at least one recipient.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** Attachments will be part of the email per default **iff** it has at least one recipient.

---

As of 01.02.2023 on `Mail Version 16.0 (3731.300.101.1.3)`:

The default behaviour seems to be that attachments will **indeed** be included when forwarding messages, but only *after* you've added **at least** one recipient.

See: `'Edit' > 'Include Attachments With Replies' > 'When Adding Recipients'`

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new Forward message, right-click the toolbar and **Customise Toolbar...** You'll see an icon for **Include Attachments**. Drag it into the toolbar. Click Done.

You can now toggle this button to include attachments or not.

Comment: Icon is inactive.  I can't click.

Comment: This does not work, since the icon is grayed out.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Edit > Attachment > and select "Include Original Attachments in Reply".

I really don't get it why Apple still doesn't make this a default.

Comment: As of 01.02.2023 on Mail Version 16.0 (3731.300.101.1.3):

The default behaviour seems to be that attachments will indeed be included when forwarding messages, but only _after_ you've added at least one recipient.

See: 'Edit' > 'Include Attachments With Replies' > 'When Adding Recipients'